# Detect browser proxy setting enabled or not using Javascript

Tags: javascript, proxy

We have a coupon download functionality in our website.  Users should download a plugin which allows them to then download the actual coupon.  Plugin download is not working in IE6 with proxy settings. It is working in all other browsers even with proxy setting.  Now, my client want to display some message to the user if the user is using IE6 with proxy.  Ex: Alert message like "You are using IE6 with proxy.  Please try in some other browser".

Now, question is - How to detect whether the browser is using proxy or not using Javascript?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why not solve this on server-side, looking at http headers for the proxy and user agent?

Comment: <!--[if lte IE 6]><script type="text/javascript">alert("You must upgrade your browser immediately. No arguments."); location.href = "http://www.microsoft.com/ie/";</script><![endif]-->

Comment: Nice auto-link regular expression Atwood, you idiot programmer.  I told you RegExs suck.

Comment: Cleiton - Thanks for your answer.  It is very helpful.  So, your code sample will work only for transparent proxies right?  Do you have any solution to detect all kind of proxies? Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with javascript. I think the best option is, what Zed has said, solve it at serve side using HTTP-HEADERS.

In **ASP.NET** you can do something like that:

```
bool IsUsingProxy = Request.Headers
            .AllKeys
            .Any(header => header.Equals("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR", 
                            StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

The only down sidee is that it will only work with users using transparent proxies.